# NAudio C# How to make/control # of bytes read from IWavePlayer?

Tags: c#, naudio

I have the following code:

```
IWavePlayer player = new WaveOut();
WaveStream reader = new WaveFileReader(filePath);
WaveChannel32 input = new WaveChannel32(reader);

AmplitudeStream ampStream = new AmplitudeStream(input);
ampStream.AmplitudeEventHandler += new EventHandler<AmplitudeArgs>(AmplitudeStreamHandler);

player.Init(ampStream);
player.Play();
```

AmplitudeStream is a class I made that implements WaveStream so that I can 'track' and send an event whenever data is read from the file. However, my problem is that I want to control how much bytes are read. Since the Read function of AmplitudeStream is being called by the Play() function, I have no idea on how I can limit the number of bytes read (it is always 35,280).

How to do this? I am using the Play() command because I want my file to play so that I can observe. So if there is another way to play the file during the Read() command, which would look something like:

```
byte[] buffer = byte[8192]
int bytesRead = 0;

do{

bytesRead = ampStream.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);

}while(bytesRead != 0);

@override
private int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{

//some command to play the file here

}
```

I would like to know. Thanks! Aside from that, is there a way to not use the WaveChannel32 class as input for my AmplitudeStream?

Answer (score 2):

have a look in the NAudio demo at how the waveform drawing is done, since this sounds exactly what you want to do. It essentially intercepts the Read, and sends an event every n samples that the drawing code can subscribe to.

**Update** the number of bytes read is a function of the playback latency - lower latency = fewer bytes read. If your source stream can only be read in block-sizes of 8192 though, I would be tempted to introduce an intermediate buffering stream.

Comment: Hi Mark! Actually, what I meant was that I want to be able to control how many bytes are read using the .play() function. Currently, whenever I use the play function, it always reads 35280 bytes. I want it to read only 8192 bytes at a time.